# jQuery get all object assigned properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, properties

Now I have an array called parameters , each item in this array has diferent custom properties , for example :

```
parameters[0]=new Object();
parameters[1]=new Object();
parameters[0].name="bla"
parameters[0].desc="bla bla"
parameters[1].from="another bla"
parameters[1].to="bla bla bla"
```

How can i state all the properties on any item , so that for example per `parameters[0]` it is 
`"name"` & `"desc"` , and for `parameters[1]` it is `"from"` , and `"to"`.

Comment: What does it mean to "state a property?"

Comment: for...in loop will return all object keys and value

Comment: to know it !! like to alert it or whatever !

Comment: @A.Wolff how to access the keys if i dont know their value . you mean iterating existing keys ?

Comment: @A.Wolff mind making a quick fiddle ?!

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(parameters[0]))`

Comment: Keep a dictionary of the properties you are interested and the use for..in and check the dictionary if the property matches. If so, do alert or whatever!

Comment: `for(var k in parameters[0])
    alert(k);`

Comment: @elclanrs exactly what i want , why dont you add an answer ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep search the easiest way was to use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames().`

Source:

[Object Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

Answer (score 3):

I can't clearly understand what you are trying to ask but this code might help you. Kindly explain more so that I may be able to help you more on this.

```
var parameters = [];
parameters[0]=new Object();
parameters[1]=new Object();
parameters[0].name="bla";
parameters[0].desc="bla bla";
parameters[1].from="another bla";
parameters[1].to="bla bla bla";

console.log(Object.keys(parameters[0]));
console.log(Object.keys(parameters[1]));
```

Comment: @ProllyGeek be aware older browser (IE8?) could not support it

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for the tip , but no problem only chrome will run this app.

Comment: @A.Wolff yea except i got downvote idk why , but i really searched for it everywhere , iam not going to remove my question though :P

Comment: @ProllyGeek can you suggest a fix where it is not supported? I am trying to find one.

Comment: @TalhaMasood https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys